# How, in python, to split up lage result of itertools.product into groups and iterate in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-itertools

In python I am using itertools.product to iterate over all possible combinations of a list of characters that produces a very large result.
However when I look at the Windows 10 Task Manager the python process executing this task is only taking 13.5% CPU.  I looked into multiprocessing in python, and found that with pool.map I can map an instance of a function to pool, and have multiple instances of the function running in parallel.  This is great, but as I am iterating over a single (very large) list and this is done in one instance of a function that takes up a large amount of time, this doesn't help me.

So the way I see it the only way to speed this up is to split the result of itertools.product into groups and iterate over the groups in parallel.  If I can get the length of the result itertools.product, I can divide it into groups by the number of processor cores I have available, and then using multiprocessing I can iterate over all these groups in parallel.

So my question is can this be done, and what is the best approach?

Maybe there is a module out there for this sort of thing?

The concept is something like this.  *(the following actually works but gives MemoryError when I try and scale it up to the full character set commented out)*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import sys, itertools, multiprocessing, functools

def process_group(iIterationNumber, iGroupSize, sCharacters, iCombinationLength, iCombintationsListLength, iTotalIterations):
    iStartIndex = 0
    if iIterationNumber > 1: iStartIndex = (iIterationNumber - 1) * iGroupSize
    iStopIndex = iGroupSize * iIterationNumber
    if iIterationNumber == iTotalIterations: iStopIndex = iCombintationsListLength
    aCombinations = itertools.product(sCharacters, repeat=iCombinationLength)
    lstCombinations = list(aCombinations)
    print("Iteration#", iIterationNumber, "StartIndex:", iStartIndex, iStopIndex)
    for iIndex in range(iStartIndex, iStopIndex):
        aCombination = lstCombinations[iIndex];
        print("Iteration#", iIterationNumber, ''.join(aCombination))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #_sCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\"""':;?/>.<,"
    _sCharacters = "123"
    _iCombinationLength = 4
    aCombinations = itertools.product(_sCharacters, repeat=_iCombinationLength)
    lstCombinations = list(aCombinations)
    _iCombintationsListLength = len(lstCombinations)
    iCPUCores = 4
    _iGroupSize = round(_iCombintationsListLength / iCPUCores)
    print("Length", _iCombintationsListLength)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(functools.partial(process_group, iGroupSize = _iGroupSize, sCharacters = _sCharacters, iCombinationLength = _iCombinationLength, iCombintationsListLength = _iCombintationsListLength, iTotalIterations = iCPUCores), range(1,iCPUCores+1))
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't share the `product()` output among subprocesses; there is no good way to break this up into chunks per process. Instead, have each subprocess generate new values but give them a prefix to start from.

Remove outer loops from the `product()` call and create groups from that. For example, you could create `len(sCharacters)` groups by decreasing `iCombinationLength` by one and passing in each element from `sCharacters` as a prefix:

```
for prefix in sCharacters:
    # create group for iCombinationLength - 1 results.
    # pass in the prefix
```

Each group then can loop over `product(sCharacters, repeat=iCombinationLength - 1)` themselves and combine that with the prefix. So group 1 starts with `'0'`, group 2 starts with `'1'`, etc.

You can extend this by using combinations of 2 or 3 or more characters. For your 10 input characters, that'd create 100 or 1000 groups, respectively. The generic version is:

```
prefix_length = 3
for prefix in product(sCharacters, repeat=prefix_length):
    # create group for iCombinationLength - prefix_length
    # pass in the prefix
```

Comment: Martin, I have updated the code to a working example... but it is not salable as you have pointed out.  See the size of the character list, how would your approach work with this?

Comment: @user2109254: exactly the same way.

Comment: Ok then I am not understanding it.  How does this increase speed, I can't see any parallel processing?

Comment: @user2109254: it lets you break up the problem into smaller subsets for each process to handle. You can't share the `product` iterator, but you can produce a *subset* of all combinations in each subprocess to handle in parallel, all you need to do is generate the prefixes.

Comment: Martijn, Thanks for the response.  I think what you are talking about is like the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262138/how-do-i-multi-process-the-itertools-product-module  I will use this guys example as this is the level of detail I need to understand how it works.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Exactly; your question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I do have one question that isn't covered in his example.  How to exit all processes once a match is found.....

Comment: Have the master process kill the rest of the processes once the first one returns with a match?