# Ways of speeding up the itertools.product in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I'm trying to create a numpy array consisting of all possible asset allocations using itertools.product.
The conditions are that allocations for each asset can be in range of zero to 100% and can rise by (100% / number of assets) increments. The allocations total sum should be 100%.

The calculations take very long time when assets number grows (10 seconds for 7 assets, 210 seconds for 8 assets and so on).
Is there a way to speed up the code somehow?
Maybe i should try using it.takewhile or multiprocessing?

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

def CreateMatrix(Increments):

    inputs = it.product(np.arange(0, 1 + Increments, Increments), repeat = int(1/Increments));
    matrix = np.ndarray((1, int(1/Increments)));
    x = 0;
    for i in inputs:
        if np.sum(i, axis = 0) == 1:
            if x > 0:
                matrix = np.r_[matrix, np.ndarray((1, int(1/Increments)))]
            matrix[x] = i
            x = x + 1

    return matrix

Assets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
Increments = 1.0 / len(Assets)
matrix = CreateMatrix(Increments);
print matrix
```

Comment: The product with 8 repetitions will have 16 million elements. Calling multiple numpy functions 16 million times is going to take a long time. Are you sure you really need an 8-dimensional product?

Comment: Take a look at how many entries you are going create in your matrix (list?).  This is a non-trivial number, and answering this question will not solve the problems that will come afterwards with your trillions of entries, e.g. "I cannot sort 10^60th elements" =)

Comment: While your implementation could be improved a *lot* (primarily through a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) approach instead of filtering a cartesian product, and not trying to append rows to an array one at a time), your array size still grows rapidly, and it'll grow way too huge to build, store, or use pretty quickly. Your best option is to use a different approach to whatever problem you were trying to use the array to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Use the stdlib `sum` instead of `numpy.sum`. This code spends most of its time computing that sum, according to cProfile.

**Profiling Code**

```py
import cProfile, pstats, StringIO
import itertools as it
import numpy as np


def CreateMatrix(Increments):
    inputs = it.product(np.arange(0, 1 + Increments, Increments), repeat = int(1/Increments));
    matrix = np.ndarray((1, int(1/Increments)));
    x = 0
    for i in inputs:
        if np.sum(i, axis=0) == 1:
            if x > 0:
                matrix = np.r_[matrix, np.ndarray((1, int(1/Increments)))]
            matrix[x] = i
            x += 1
    return matrix

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
Assets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
Increments = 1.0 / len(Assets)
matrix = CreateMatrix(Increments);
print matrix
pr.disable()
s = StringIO.StringIO()
sortby = 'cumulative'
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortby)
ps.print_stats()
print s.getvalue()
```

**Truncated Output**

```
         301565912 function calls (301565864 primitive calls) in 294.255 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   26.294   26.294  294.254  294.254 product.py:7(CreateMatrix)
 43046721   41.948    0.000  267.762    0.000 Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:1966(sum)
 43046723   60.071    0.000  217.863    0.000 Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:69(_wrapreduction)
 43046723  124.341    0.000  124.341    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
 43046723   14.630    0.000   14.630    0.000 Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:70(<dictcomp>)
 43046721   12.629    0.000   12.629    0.000 {getattr}
 43098200    7.958    0.000    7.958    0.000 {isinstance}
 43046724    6.191    0.000    6.191    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
     6434    0.047    0.000    0.199    0.000 Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py:316(__getitem__)
```

**Timing Experiments**

`numpy.sum`

```py
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

def CreateMatrix(Increments):

    inputs = it.product(np.arange(0, 1 + Increments, Increments), repeat = int(1/Increments));
    matrix = np.ndarray((1, int(1/Increments)));
    x = 0;
    for i in inputs:
        if np.sum(i, axis = 0) == 1:
            if x > 0:
                matrix = np.r_[matrix, np.ndarray((1, int(1/Increments)))]
            matrix[x] = i
            x = x + 1

    return matrix

Assets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
Increments = 1.0 / len(Assets)
matrix = CreateMatrix(Increments);
```

```bash
$ python -m timeit --number=3 --verbose "$(cat product.py)"
raw times: 738 696 697
3 loops, best of 3: 232 sec per loop
```

Stdlib `sum`

```py
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

def CreateMatrix(Increments):

    inputs = it.product(np.arange(0, 1 + Increments, Increments), repeat = int(1/Increments));
    matrix = np.ndarray((1, int(1/Increments)));
    x = 0;
    for i in inputs:
        if sum(i) == 1:
            if x > 0:
                matrix = np.r_[matrix, np.ndarray((1, int(1/Increments)))]
            matrix[x] = i
            x = x + 1

    return matrix

Assets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
Increments = 1.0 / len(Assets)
matrix = CreateMatrix(Increments);
```

```bash
$ python -m timeit --number=3 --verbose "$(cat product.py)"
raw times: 90.5 84.3 85.3
3 loops, best of 3: 28.1 sec per loop
```

There are many more ways to get your solution faster, as other folks have said in their comments. Take a look at [How do I "multi-process" the itertools product module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262138/how-do-i-multi-process-the-itertools-product-module) for an idea of how to use `multiprocessing` to speed this up. No matter what you do: clever algorithm, concurrency or both, replace the sum function; it's a lot of speed up for very little effort.

---

**Update**

I was able to further improve run time after realizing that `matrix` is merely the rows from the Cartesian product which sum to 1. Rather than reallocating `matrix` within a loop, compute the sums of rows in the Cartesian product and construct `matrix` from them. This is also much easier to understand.

```py
def CreateMatrix(Increments):
    inputs = it.product(
        np.arange(0, 1 + Increments, Increments),
        repeat=int(1/Increments)
    )
    matrix = np.array(
        [row for row in inputs if sum(row) == 1]
    )
    return matrix
```

```
raw times: 79.4 78.5 78
3 loops, best of 3: 26 sec per loop
```

**Future Work**

The number of rows to search (rows in product set) increases much more rapidly than the number of rows in the output, `matrix`.

[image: Input Size vs Output Size]

It's critical to develop a method for computing the rows which sum to 1, in the order produced by `itertools.product`, in order to construct `matrix` for larger problem sizes.